# Accessing a ListView item's text from Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, android-listview, android-menu, android-actionbar

I need to access the text in a ListView item through a long click selection. For old Android versions I have successfully done this with context menus with the code below.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    String text = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.getText:
            getText(text);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

For newer Android versions, however, I would like to do this with the Contextual Action Bar but can't figure out how to extract the selected text after having selected an item in the bar. The below code does not work.

```
    myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    myListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        String text = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.contextDelete:
                    getText(text);
                    return true;;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        //Other actionmode methods...
    });
```

The Contextual Action Bar shows up ok, but when picking an item from it I get a NullPointerException at the AdapterContextMenuInfo line, since this was obviously made for context menus and not action bars. Is there some equivalent for this for Action bars perhaps? Or how can I get the ListView item text in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getCheckedItemPositions()` on `ListView` will return the item positions the user has checked, and `getCheckedItemIds()` will return their ID values if you are using something like `CursorAdapter`.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Honeycomb/ActionModeMC) demonstrating the use of `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` on API Level 11+ and falling back to context menus on older devices.

Comment: Thanks, the sample project helped me out! A separate question though, how do I make it visible that an item has been selected? For me all the items look the same even after selected.

Comment: @mattboy: "A separate question though, how do I make it visible that an item has been selected?" -- do something in the row layout. In the sample project, there are checkmarks down the right side, and you check and uncheck rows to determine what the action mode should affect. In the case of Gmail, they use checkboxes on the left.

Comment: How i can get text from TextView in each ListView item?

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the `getCheckedItemIds()` method on the `ListView` object and it returned nothing (I was not using a `Cursor` object). Turns out this is a common problem people have been facing. So I came up with a workaround for this. In my situation, I had to use the item IDs for creating notifications (just trying out some sample code) so this is what I did to get them:

I created an `ArrayList` to store the IDs of all the items that have been selected. Every time an item is checked, the `onItemCheckedStateChanged(..)` method is called. We can use this method to update the `ArrayList` of IDs based on the state change. Then we can use the IDs stored in this list when the user chooses an option and the `onActionItemClicked()` method is called. Here's the code:

```
lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            private ArrayList<Long> checkedIds = new ArrayList<Long>();

                    //Code omitted for brevity

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                menu.add(0, 1, 0, R.string.context_create_notification);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                switch(item.getItemId()){
                case 1:
                    for(long id : checkedIds){
                        createNotification(id+1);
                    }
                    mode.finish();
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                    long id, boolean checked) {

                if(checked){
                    checkedIds.add(id);
                } else{
                    Iterator<Long> iter = checkedIds.iterator();
                    while(iter.hasNext()){
                        long stored = (Long) iter.next();
                        if(stored == id){
                            iter.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```